# How to unregister a ComposablePart from CompositionContainer

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, mef, composition

I am using MEF with a static CompositionContainer. My classes use this container like this:

```
public void SomeClass
{
    [Import(typeof(AnotherClass)]
    private AnotherClass Instance {get;set;}

    public SomeClass()
    {
        MEFContext.RegisterAttributedPart(this); // this basically calls CompositionContainer.ComposeParts(this);
    }
}
```

The problem now is, that the Instance of SomeClass will never be released because the CompositionContainer keeps an instance to it. How would i be able to release this instance?

Additional informations:

- AnotherClass has a PartCreationPolicy with CreationPolicy.Shared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .NET 4 it seems that the used implementation of MEF does not support child containers and filtered catalogs. I solved the problem above by creating a new container and use a catalog which only contains the necessary items. This container is disposed when I do not need it anymore. In .NET 4.5 this could be solved with child containers.

Answer (score 0):

[CompositionContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.compositioncontainer.aspx) implements IDisposable. Are you calling Dispose or the using pattern on your CompositionContainer and releasing the reference to it?